# Выражение "острая грань"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, значение-слов

*Можно ли **ухватиться** за острую грань?*

Некоторые толковые словари дают такое определение грани: кромка, край и ребро ( в том числе и словарь Даля). Острая грань — достаточно часто встречающееся выражение в литературе, причем *в геометрическом* контексте.

Answer (score 1):

"Он потерял равновесие, попытался **ухватиться рукой за острую грань камня** в стенном проломе, но пальцы соскользнули и началось падение".

Острой гранью **условно** называют фигуру, соответствующую **двугранному острому углу**. Это пространственная геометрическая фигура, образованная двумя полуплоскостями, исходящими из одной прямой, а также часть пространства, ограниченная этими полуплоскостями.

Получается, что **острая грань** составлена **двумя гранями**, образующими острый угол. Ухватиться за нее трудно, а порезаться легко: **"Острая грань** скалы врезалась в пальцы".

**Примеры**

И вдруг на фоне темного неба, загроможденного тучами, пронзительно, как вспышка, высветилась кинжально **острая грань** обелиска. [Евгений Носов. Шопен, соната номер два (1973)]

Пандион достал самый маленький из подаренных ему камней юга и осторожно провел острой гранью по краю голубовато-зеленого кристалла. [И. А. Ефремов. На краю Ойкумены (1945-1946)]

Переносное значение:

А Цыганок скрипел зубами, бранился и плевал ― его человеческий мозг, поставленный **на чудовищно острую грань** между жизнью и смертью, распадался на части, как комок сухой и выветрившейся глины. [Л. Н. Андреев. Рассказ о семи повешенных (1908)]

Comment: Arina, примеров много. Но поверхность же плоская, как она может быть острой? Угол - понятно, может быть острым, за него можно ухватиться.

Comment: Серж, это понятие многозначное: и поверхность,и  ребро В словаре: ГРАНЬ, -и; ж. 1. Плоская поверхность предмета, составляющая угол с другой такой же поверхностью. Куб имеет шесть граней. Грани бриллианта. // Ребро, образуемое двумя пересекающимися плоскостями.

Comment: Ребро - эта линяя соединяющая эти плоские поверхности. За нее вряд ли можно уцепиться.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно толковым словарям "грань" - это одна из плоских сторон какого-либо предмета, "ребро" - (то есть линия, соединяющая грани). Поэтому определение "острый" приминительно к этому значению не совсем корректно.

Острая грань - это скорее переносное значение: тонко, ярко выраженное различие. Поэтому даже в этом значении "ухватиться за острою грань" тоже является некорректным.

Answer (score 0):

Выскажусь в поддержку **Sibylla** и сошлюсь на [этот словарь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=LUFqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=%22%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%22%20%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD&source=bl&ots=nnCEutEvUY&sig=3iIGZh89CZPENv_izbNeMVpokFo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieirGrksbYAhXKYVAKHbIEBXkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%22%20%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD&f=false):

> грань 2.3, преим. МН.
>
> ПРИМЕРЫ. Острая грань; грани осколков стекла.
>
> ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. 'Часть объекта А1, образуемая пересечением под острым углом
>   двух его граней или двух участков его поверхности'.
>
> ...
>
> СИН: ребро, край.

Ничего не поделаешь — словоупотребление в естественных языках не всегда согласовано с научными терминами.